# wrong variables format when filling yaml with Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a yml file that I need to fill with Jenkins.

```
global:         
  name: 'my_name'
  code: 'my_code'
```

So, I define Jenkins params:

```
string(name: 'NAME', defaultValue: 'Nightly Valid', description: 'Nightly Valid Name')
string(name: 'CODE', defaultValue: 'NIGHTLY', description: '')
```

And further in my Jenkinsfile, I have:

```
           script {
               def filename = "configuration.yml"
               def yaml = readYaml file: filename

               // General data
               yaml.global.name = "${params.NAME}"
               yaml.global.code = "${params.CODE}"
               // ...

               sh "rm $filename"
               writeYaml file: filename, data: yaml
```

When I do that, I get:

```
global:         
      name: '''my_name'''
      code: '''my_code'''
```

How can I do to just have:

```
global:         
      name: 'my_name'
      code: 'my_code'
```

Comment: Not sure but "${params.NAME}" is GStringImpl, try to convert it to string directly "${params.NAME}".toString()

Comment: it seems that it worked. Please put it as answer :)

Comment: added as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"${params.NAME}"** is **GStringImpl**, try to convert it to string directly: `"${params.NAME}".toString()`